# how to write a predicate function

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a class like this:

```
    public class A
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public bool IsOK { get; set}
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
    }
    public class C:B
    {
        public string test2 { get; set; }
    }
```

In my main class:

```
    static void main()
    {
        var a = new B() { Username = "User1", IsOK = false };
        var b = new B() { Username = "user2", IsOK = false };
        var c = new C() { Username = "admin", IsOK = true };
        List<B> bclasses = new List<B>() { a, b, c };
        // I want to filter out username is user2 or IsOK is true
        var username = "user2";
        var select = bclasses.Where(b => b.IsOK || b.Username == username).ToList();
    }
```

But I don't want to write the code "b => b.IsOk || b.UserName == username" every time.
How can I write a predicate inside Where so that it is concise?
Thanks.

Comment: how do u accessing `Username`  and `IsOk` when writing `new B(){...}` ,did you men to write `new A() {... } `, also where is class C?

Comment: That code makes no sense, as is. B has no IsOk property nor a UserName property. Or is B actually derived from A ?

Comment: The code above need to be corrected. There is class C. On class B, do not have the fields you have mentioned. However you can use a Predicate if you don't want to repeat the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either declare the predicate as a `Func<A, bool>`:

```
Func<A, bool> predicate = x => x.IsOK || x.Username == username;
```

Or you can declare it as a local function:

```
bool predicate(A x) => x.IsOK || x.Username == username;
```

(Unfortunately, you can't use `Predicate<A>` because that is not a type that is accepted by `IEnumerable.Where()`.)

In either case, if it is defined inside the method, it can capture the local `username` and therefore does not need to have a parameter for that.

Here's a corrected and compilable example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public class A
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public bool   IsOK     { get; set; }
    }

    public class B: A
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
    }

    public class C: B
    {
        public string test2 { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var     a        = new B() { Username = "User1", IsOK = false };
            var     b        = new B() { Username = "user2", IsOK = false };
            var     c        = new C() { Username = "admin", IsOK = true };
            List<B> bclasses = new List<B>() { a, b, c };

            // I want to filter out username is user2 or IsOK is true
            var username = "user2";

            bool predicate(A x) => x.IsOK || x.Username == username; // <=== Here is the predicate.

            var select = bclasses.Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, supposing you actually want to pass in the `username` argument to the predicate instead of capturing it, you can just add a parameter to the predicate like so:

```
bool predicate(A x, string name) => x.IsOK || x.Username == name;
```

And then you would pass `username` to the predicate inside the `Where()` like so:

```
var select = bclasses.Where(item => predicate(item, username)).ToList();
```

Comment: Great answer that exactly meets my need. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think you may need to implement Function (Func), not Predicate.

Thank you @Fildor for pointing me the unused delegate, so that I encapsulate it to something like this:

```
 Func<List<A>, string, List<A>> selectValidUser = (users, filterName) =>
 {
    return users.Where(u => u.IsOK || u.Username == filterName).ToList();
 };

 var selectedUsers = selectValidUser(bclasses, username);
```

Comment: Another great solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that accepts a B or a C and returns a Boolean indicating whether to include it in your list. In other words, a `Func<B,bool>`. You could define it this way:

```
Func<B,bool> predicate = x => x.IsOK || x.Username == username;
```

And to use it, just pass it to `Where`.

```
var selection = bclasses.Where( predicate ).ToList();
```

Comment: why not use `Predicate` with `FindAl()`l ?